# Does Intuitive Attack work with melee and ranged touch attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, touch-attacks

The feat **Intuitive attack** has as its benefit

> With a simple weapon of your size or a natural weapon, you may use your Wisdom modifier instead of your Strength modifier on attack rolls. (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 44)

Does this benefit apply to melee touch attacks and ranged touch attacks?

I know that it says Strength modifier and not Dexterity, but it does not specifically *exclude* ranged attacks; for example, a crossbow's a simple weapon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes and no.** The feat doesn't help ranged touch attacks, but it does apply to melee touch attacks.

"Instead of" [means](https://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=define%20instead&oq=define%20instead&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4103j0j7) "in place of." If you use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength modifier on a roll that doesn't usually use your Strength modifier (such as a ranged touch attack), the result is that the roll uses your Wisdom modifier the same way it would otherwise have used your Strength modifier: Not at all.

[Melee touch attacks do use your Strength modifier, though](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#touchAttacks). Yes, this makes very little sense. It means they can benefit from this feat, though.

3.5rd edition being what it is, there are options out there that allow you to use your Strength or Wisdom modifiers on ranged touch attack rolls; *Zen Archery* from *Complete Warrior* is an example of the latter. You could conceivably such an option in place of or combination with Intuitive Attack to get the effect you want. Thanks to Eikre for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gm Joe that it does not apply to ranged attacks but Zen archery would.

I would argue however that intuitive attack does not apply to melee touch attacks since they are not natural attacks (though in some circumstances may be delivered by natural attacks).

If you were a creature who had natural attacks ex tentacles or a slam attack then maybe but for a standard humanoid who has their fists no.

If using fists, you count as unarmed unless you have improved unarmed strike (ex monk) and in that case they could be argued to be natural weapons (but slightly wobbly thinking).

Since you count as unarmed you are not making a weapon attack of any form and so can't benefit from intuitive attack there.

Note that Zen archery applies to any ranged attack roll, not just weapon attacks and so absolutely applies to ranged touch attacks

Regarding the very last part of the question about using intuitive attack for simple ranged weapons, yes it doesn't call out melee but unless they use strength there is nothing to replace with wisdom. A strength based simple thrown weapon may apply or if there was some other way to make a ranged weapon use strength mod instead first. So basically I again agree with dm Joe

Comment: [SRD on unarmed attacks] (http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm)
"Armed" Unarmed Attacks
_"Sometimes a character’s or creature’s unarmed attack counts as an armed attack. A monk, a character with the Improved Unarmed Strike feat, a spellcaster delivering a touch attack spell, and a creature with natural physical weapons all count as being armed."_
On the base of touch attack, ranged attack on the other hand.....

Comment: Sure a touch attack counts as armed however it is not a simple weapon nor is it a natural weapon. Unless you can deliver the touch attack *through* a simple weapon or natural weapon (or **maybe** unarmed strike) then you can't apply wisdom in place of strength.

Comment: "Armed" Unarmed Attacks "*Sometimes a character’s or creature’s unarmed attack counts as an armed attack*. A monk, a character with the Improved Unarmed Strike feat, *a spellcaster delivering a touch attack spell*, and a creature with natural physical weapons all count as being armed."

_"Sometimes a character’s or creature’s unarmed attack counts as an armed attack"_ 
_"a spellcaster delivering a touch attack spell"_ 
A spellcaster delivering a touch attack spell is performing an "Armed" Unarmed strike.                       




An Unarmed strike is a simple weapon

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you it's more just pedantic on my part. A touch spell can be delivered as a punch or through a punch I agree, and in that case it applies but unless you actually say you are touch attacking by punching/slapping or otherwise striking the assumption is just a touch. Generally speaking the wizard doesn't punch the armored paladin with his shivering touch because he'd break his wrist. Could he? Of course he could. I'm just saying you need to be specific that you're doing it as an unarmed strike